# Why is the Turkish president's surname is spelt in English as Erdogan, with g?

Tags: orthography, translation, names, surnames

I recently got puzzled as to why American journalists spell the surname of the current Turkish president in articles written in English as Erdogan, with g (see, e.g., this [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/06/20/world/europe/erdogan-trump-istanbul-election.html) in *New York Times*). We spell his surname as エルドアン, which does not include the g sound.

In the original language, Turkish, his surname is spelt as Erdoğan, using the letter ğ, not g.

The Turkish letters ğ and g are two different letters. The letter ğ has no sound on its own, with its effect varying depending on the location in a word and the surrounding vowels. This letter can have zero phonetic effect, slightly lengthen the preceding vowel, or somewhat separate two vowels. The letter g, in contrast, has its own consonant sound, which is practically the same as the English sound g in the English words "gross," "big," and "bogan."

The Turks pronounce the surname of their president as /ˈeɾdo‿an/, not making even a slightest consonant sound between o and a. They simply pronounce о and а distinctly.

My question is this: Besides the visual similarity between the letters ğ and g, is there any other reason why Erdoğan and many other Turkish proper names are spelt in English with the letter g?

Being not a native English speaker, I possibly do not see some important factors that native English speakers easily see, so I decided to ask here.

Comment: Because they don't speak Turkish and just write what they see? Which English alphabet letter do you think should be used?

Comment: @WeatherVane : One option is to do what the Albanians do: They spell his surname as Erdoan, simply omitting ğ, which is absent in their alpabet just like in the English alphabet.

Comment: So what are you actually asking? "Why are American journalists ignorant about Turkish?" We also say "Paris" with the silent **s** pronounced.

Comment: Why is España spelled "Spain" and Deutschland spelled "Germany"?

Comment: @WeatherVane : No, I noticed that even Turkish city names containing ğ are usually spelt in English with g. So apparently it is not about American journalists only. Maybe there is a rule to bilnldy transliterate non-English proper names to English exactly as they are written in the original language regardless of the diacritic signs and original pronunciation?

Comment: It's called "[Anglicising](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/anglicize)".

Comment: @WeatherVane : I know that the letter **ğ** was pronounced in the Turkish language long ago, so maybe the replacement ğ → g is simply an old continuous tradition of writing Turkish proper names in English, that is, a tradition that exists simply because no one was enthusiastic enough to change it after ğ lost its own sound in Turkish?

Comment: I don't think people read that much into it. Most people don't know Turkish, let alone its history and etymology. And more generally, if you try to use foreign ways of speaking about foreign things to your peers, they think there is something wrong with you. If you return from Paris talking about "Paree" they will roll their eyes at you for being pretentious.

Comment: @WeatherVane : Even journalists who write about Turkey? In my language we write his surname without g. And the Koreans write his surname without the g sound, too.

Comment: Well your written language does not seem to bear even a passing resemblance to Turkish, so that's rather different.

Comment: @WeatherVane : And how do Americans pronounce the surname of the Turkish president? Let's suppose you see the name "Erdogan" in an article written in English. Would you pronounce "Erdogan" in analogy to the word "bogan," with g?

Comment: I am not American. I know some Turkish people we but don't talk politics, so I have never noticed how it should be pronounced. If I saw it written Iwould pronounce what I saw, unless I knew better. What is the **bogan** you keep mentioning anyway? Does it have a silent **g**, a soft or a hard one?

Comment: @WeatherVane : It is just the closest English word that came to my mind, because it ends with -ogan. I know this word from an Australian friend of mine, (Definition: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bogan ). Ah, now I recalled another word: slogan. I guess that this is how Erdogan would be read...

Comment: @WeatherVane : slogan /ˈsləʊɡ(ə)n/ , bogan /ˈbəʊɡ(ə)n/ . So I guess that the first instinct of English speakers would be to read ''Erdogan'' as /eɾˈdəʊɡ(ə)n /.

Comment: @WeatherVane : I think another option would be to write "Erdoghan," in analogy to "throughout," in which "gh" is not pronounced.

Comment: @Mitsuko you might consider too that it could be laziness, not ignorance. In the days of metal type-setting there quite likely wasn't a **ğ** to be had especially at short notice to meet the press deadline. It's a similar problem with computer typography: my keyboard has the 26 letters of the English alphabet. If I want anything else I have to find one and copy/paste it (as here) or using say Word, have a look through the menus to find one. Most people are not as thoughtful or as accurate as you.

Comment: +1. Interesting question—and I appreciate the thought you've put into trying to account for the English spelling.

Comment: You're making a lot of fuss about nothing. In any case, it's better to use the usual BrE "g" than omit it altogether. Some publications do in fact use the Turkish "g".

Comment: Your question may be more about Japanese pronunciation than it is about English. エルドアン (rendered by you in katakana because it is a foreign name) is really only a rough approximation, a block formation of phonemes that are and can only be very imperfectly rendered in Japanese. *Erdogan* is approximated in English as well, but not to the extent that it is in your native tongue. Look at some of your 外来語 borrowed from English sometime (e.g., 
ワードプロセッサ), which ought to show you the stark difference if you listen to them against native pronunciations of the originals.

Comment: @Mitsuko you might also wonder why Turkish people spell the English **I** (capital letter **i**) as **ı** which is not an English letter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Besides the visual similarity between the letters ğ and g, is there any other reason why Erdoğan and many other Turkish proper names are spelt in English with the letter g?

The visual (and historical) relationship between ğ and g is the most important factor. There isn't a big tradition in English of spelling names from other languages according to an English-based transcription of the names' pronunciations. Instead, names tend to have a spelling based on:

1. The original spelling (if the source language is written in the Latin alphabet); or...
2. If the source language is not written in the Latin alphabet, some existing transliteration or transcription that is viewed as a "standard" (not necessarily one designed to show pronunciation to monolingual English speakers). E.g. the pinyin transcription of Chinese has become more or less standard, even though it uses letters like X and Q in ways that are unknown in the spelling system used for English words.

Sometimes there are older spellings that don't follow one of these two patterns, but they tend to become deprecated over time. E.g. the spelling ["Hindoo" has now been replaced more or less entirely by "Hindu"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hindoo%2CHindu&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHindoo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHindu%3B%2Cc0); the spelling "Koran" has been overtaken by the spelling "[Qur'an](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Koran%2CQuran%2CQur%27an&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CKoran%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQuran%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQur%27an%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CKoran%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQuran%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQur'an%3B%2Cc0)".

Removing "[funny foreign lines, dots and squiggles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:Naming_conventions_(use_English)/diacritics)" from letters or words is another habit of English speakers. Hence, Erdoğan > Erdogan. English speakers don't instinctively think of ğ as a separate letter from g; they think of it as a g with something on top. The use of diacritics in English texts varies a lot and is discussed in other posts on this site, so I won't try to cover it here. It is not impossible to encounter the spelling "Erdoğan" in an English text.

Comment: Wow. That's my new favorite lame Wikipedia argument (displacing "yog[h]urt").